# webdriver - how to select a link from within a list

Tags: webdriver

this is the source - the link is within an unordered list (Configuration) and the item I want to click on is KPI Types - how with webdriver?

```
    <div id="headerList">
<div id="wrap">
<div id="meta">
</div>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="nav">
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li>
</li>
<li class="secondary">
</li>
<li class="secondary">
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
Configuration
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/edrs/validation">Validation</a>
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/edrs/kpi/kpiTypes">KPI Types</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1>Kpi</h1>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

and the link has text KPI Types

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

```
By Text: KPI Types
By XPath: //a[text()='KPI Types']
```

In c#:

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("KPI Types")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='KPI Types']")).Click();
```

Or if you want to restrict it specifically to the Configuration list:

```
By XPath: //li[text()='Configuration']//a[text()='KPI Types']
```

In c#:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[text()='Configuration']//a[text()='KPI Types']")).Click();
```

Does that answer your question?